# How to model data for similar requests?

Tags: java, angular, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I have an issue, I'm not sure how should I model the data from the backend when I have some really similar views on the front, particularly some forms.
For example in one of them the user sends an id for a seller and a product code, but in another one the inputs ask for an id seller, a product code, and two dates.
This is silly case probable but there are some others too, and I didn't know if I was supposed to duplicate data on the model or what.
Is there some design pattern one should follow or some convention?
If it helps, I'm <strike>trying to use</strike> using Angular on the front and java for backend.

Comment: It sounds so far like what you *really* want is query parameters, and if you're using Spring MVC, you may be able to collect them all into a Querydsl `Predicate` for the server-side controller argument.

Answer (score 0):

On back-end side, we usually have a controller with the endpoint which takes a model that comprises all the possible fields.

```
class Model { Object id, code, date1, date2; }
```

It's up to the controller to determine which service (or which method of the service) it should delegate work to:

```
{id, code} -> service1
{id, code, date1, date2} -> service2
```

Another approach suggests including optional parameters. In your case, they are two dates:

```
class Model { Object id, code; }

{model*} -> service1
{model*, date1, date2} -> service2
```